# How to model the assembler block to take the varying input quantity with the help of a variable or Function

Tags: anylogic

Hello guys I had created a model regarding a bus terminal in Anylogic process modelling library. There are two source blocks, one regarding passengers which will have their arrival rate according to a database table and other source regarding bus arrival rate. They both will combine at a assembler block which is given a journey time. Now the assembler block needs two input quantities. First one is regarding quantity of bus and value 1 is assigned to it. Second one is regarding passengers whose value is changing continously according to the database. How can I assign the value of number of passengers waiting in the queue and also conveyor to the assembler block input quantity[The screenshot is attached in the link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkZYh.png)

Answer (score -1):

Put block "wait" at the location as shown in the RED circle in the picture here [image]

Then add a variable to represent number of passenger for the next bus (I use variable name "varNumPerson" in this description)

In Assembler Block (named journey in your flow), put the following code

[image]
[image]

Comment: this is a bad answer first because you can't loop through a wait block like you did without getting errors at some point, second if you don't have the number of people you need in the wait block the number of passengers will never arrive, third because if passengers haven't arrived yet for the bus and you want to change varNumPerson you can't... and forth, which is not your fault... using an assembler for this is not a good idea